# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following: % The symbol "% was inserted before "&" to continue

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

```
DECLARE

invalid_product EXCEPTION;

BEGIN 

UPDATE product

SET name = '&product_description'

WHERE productid = 12;

IF SQL&NOTFOUND THEN

RAISE invalid_product;

END IF;

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION 

 WHEN invalid_product THEN

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('invalid product number.');

END;
```

```
DECLARE

  c_id customer.id%type:= -8;

  c_name customer.Name%type;

  c_addr customer.address%type;

  invalid_id EXCEPTION;

BEGIN

 IF c_id <0 THEN

  RAISE invalid_id;

  ELSE

  SELECT name,address INTO c_name,c_addr

  FROM customer

  WHERE id = c_id;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('name' || c_name);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('addresS:' || c_addr);

  END IF;

EXCEPTION

  WHEN invalid_id THEN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('invalid customer id!');

  WHEN no_data_found THEN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no such customer');

  WHEN OTHERS THEN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR');

END;
```

> problem:PLS-00201: identifier 'CUSTOMER.ID' must be declared.

Comment: What is this - do you have two unrelated questions, and you crammed them both here? For the second error - does the `CUSTOMER` table exist? Does it have an `ID` column (and not, for example, `CUSTOMER_ID`)?

Comment: yeah your are right in 2ND question CUSTOMER table does not excit,thankyou i found the error

Answer (score 1):

It is

```
SQL%NOTFOUND
```

not

```
SQL&NOTFOUND
```

---

You commented that it isn't working; it is, for me. Have a look:

```
SQL> select * from product;

 PRODUCTID NAME
---------- --------------------
        13 some name

SQL> declare
  2    invalid_product exception;
  3  begin
  4    update product
  5      set name = '&product_description'
  6      where productid = 12;
  7
  8    if sql%notfound then
  9       raise invalid_product;
 10    end if;
 11
 12    commit;
 13  exception
 14    when invalid_product then
 15      dbms_output.put_line('invalid product number.');
 16  end;
 17  /
Enter value for product_description:
invalid product number.                     --> here's your message

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: once again thankyou for these minors mistake❤

Comment: DECLARE

invalid_product EXCEPTION;

BEGIN 

UPDATE product

SET name = '%product_description'

WHERE productid = 12;

IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN

RAISE invalid_product;

END IF;

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION 

 WHEN invalid_product THEN

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('invalid product number.');

END

Comment: its not working

Comment: It *is* working.  Did you enable setveroutput? @Justin, `sql%notfound` "yields TRUE if an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement affected no rows, or a SELECT INTO statement returned no rows. Otherwise, it yields FALSE.". Why does it not make sense in this context?

Comment: @Littlefoot - You're right.  I misread the code and removed my comment.